# How to read multiple txt files from one folder

Tags: python, file, operating-system, archive

Is there any method in any python library where I can read multiple txt files from one folder. I have the following code:

```
path = '/home/paste/archives'

files = filter(isfile, glob.glob('%s/*'%path))
for names in files:
    try:
        with open(names) as f:
            print (names)
    except IOError as exc:
        if exc.errno != errno.EISDIR:
            raise
```

But the code reads all files from the "archives" folder. I would like to read only .txt files. How do I do?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Find all files in a directory with extension .txt in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3964681/find-all-files-in-a-directory-with-extension-txt-in-python)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can limit the glob search with

```
files = filter(isfile, glob.glob('%s/*.txt' % path))
```

Answer (score 0):

With the following snippet, you get all of the files and directories in a given directory and selects only those which have `.txt` extension:

`files = [file for file in os.listdir(path) if file.endswith('.txt')]`

Consider my answer if you have a lot of files in one folder (and no subdirectories where you want to get `.txt` files from) as it is faster.